# Pandas DataFrame find the most common string from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I have code that combines all names and calculates statistics from them and counts their number of occurrences. I added another column to this. How can I print the most common name from a different dataframe? In my code it means, that I would like to find the most common car brand in which voivodships.

I scraped data like this :

```
'Mercedes-Benz Klasa S', 4390.0, '(Dolnośląskie)']
['Mitsubishi Carisma 1.8', 3999.0, '(Pomorskie)']
['Audi A4 1.6', 4000.0, '(Łódzkie)']
```

```
 for offer in all_offers:
        # get the interesting data and write to file

        title = offer.find('a', class_='offer-title__link').text.strip()

        price = offer.find('span', class_='offer-price__number').text.strip().replace(' ', '').replace('\nPLN', '').replace('\nEUR', '')
        location = offer.find('span', class_='ds-location-region').text.strip()

        item = [title, float(price.replace(",", ".") ),location]
        data.append(item)
        print(item)
```

```
for name in  [
  'Alfa Romeo','Aston Martin', 'Audi',']:

    print('---', name,'pojemność od 2000cm3' '---')
    cars = df[df['title'].str.contains(name)]


    print('count:', len(cars))

    print('price min    :', cars['price'].min())
    print('price average:', cars['price'].mean())
    print('price max    :', cars['price'].max())


    cars.plot.hist(title=name)
    plt.show()
```

and the voivodships

```
for voivodships in ['('(Śląskie)', '(Świętokrzyskie)', '(Warmińsko-mazurskie)', '(Wielkopolskie)','(Zachodniopomorskie)']:


    locations= df[df['location'].str.contains(voivodships)]
    print('---', voivodships, '---')
    print('ilość ogłoszeń w :', len(voivodships))
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample or dummy of the data that you are using? Possibly it is simpler to use the aggregation functions that pandas provides rather building your own using loops.

Comment: I added this to my question

Comment: Thank you. I guess every row is a sale of the car ('Mercedes-Benz Klasa S') at a price (4390.0) in a woiwedship (Dolnośląskie)?

Comment: Yes of course, its in polish language :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need loops and you probably shouldn't use them.

Here's a solution using only pandas. I extended your dataset a little.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
    ['Mercedes-Benz Klasa S', 4390.0, '(Dolnośląskie)'],
    ['Mitsubishi Carisma 1.8', 3999.0, '(Pomorskie)'],
    ['Audi A4 1.6', 5790.0, '(Łódzkie)'],
    ['Mercedes-Benz Klasa S', 2390.0, '(Dolnośląskie)'],
    ['Mitsubishi Carisma 1.8', 3999.0, '(Dolnośląskie)'],
    ['Audi A6 2.0', 7000.0, '(Łódzkie)'],
    ['Mercedes-Benz Klasa S', 5390.0, '(Łódzkie)'],
    ['Audi A3 1.6', 4000.0, '(Dolnośląskie)'],
], columns=['make_model', 'price', 'region'])
df.region = df.region.str.slice(1,-1)
df['make'] = df.make_model.str.split(' ').str[0]
df.pivot_table(
    index=['region', 'make'], 
    aggfunc={'price':['mean', 'min', 'max'], 'make':'count'}
)
```

Please see the inline comments for further explanation. Result:

```
                           count     max    mean     min
region       make                                       
Dolnośląskie Audi              1  4000.0  4000.0  4000.0
             Mercedes-Benz     2  4390.0  3390.0  2390.0
             Mitsubishi        1  3999.0  3999.0  3999.0
Pomorskie    Mitsubishi        1  3999.0  3999.0  3999.0
Łódzkie      Audi              2  7000.0  6395.0  5790.0
             Mercedes-Benz     1  5390.0  5390.0  5390.0
```

If you simply want to see the most frequent make by region, this will do:

```
df.groupby('region')['make'].agg([
    lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0],
    lambda x: x.value_counts().values[0]
])
```

Here you group by region and then, within this group, count the values for makes and take the first, most frequent one.

Comment: It looks good, but my problem is, that data are from websraping. Data likes car, price are diffrent for another day. It's possible to dataframe without adding records?
I would like to print one, most common brand in each voivodship.

Comment: Yes, it is. I amended the question. Hope that helps.

Comment: There is still a problem. Maybe i show my whole code, because I don't know where I have a mistake.
[link](https://codeshare.io/5NldL8)

Comment: I don't think that's a specific enough question for Stackoverflow. But at first glance your data frame has a column 'location' and you are aggregating on 'voivodship'.

Comment: I change to lvoivodships in both, but there is still an error : with `  df.pivot_table(`
and `KeyError: 'voivodships'`